# Vim doesn't display colors

Tags: vim, colors

I run a Debian 7.8 server, installed all vim packages I could think of.

My .profile contains:

```
if [ -e /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color ]; then
        export TERM='xterm-256color'
else
        export TERM='xterm-color'
fi
```

My .vimrc contains:

```
set t_Co=256
set t_AB=^[[48;5;%dm
set t_AF=^[[38;5;%dm
```

And yet when I open a random cpp files and set :syntax on I don't get any colors, but this:

```
^[[38;5;14m//#include <unistd.h>
^[[38;5;81m#include ^[[38;5;13m"bouchonWifi.h"
^[[38;5;81m#include ^[[38;5;13m"string.h"
```

I've checked that my terminal can display colors thanks to a perl script that shows all 256 colors, ls is colored...

How to get colors to display properly in vim?

Comment: seems related with the t_AF, try commenting t_AB and t_AF lines and see what happens

Comment: Doesn't change a thing

Comment: make sure that `^[[` is input as `Ctrl-V <Esc> [`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.memoryhole.net/~kyle/vimrc.html):

```
if !has("gui_running")
    if &term == 'dterm'
        set tsl=0 " Sun's terminal sucks bigtime
    elseif has("terminfo") && ! (&term == 'linux' || &term == 'Eterm' || &term == 'vt220' || &term == 'nsterm-16color' || &term == 'xterm-16color')
        " Force these terminals to accept my authority! (default)
        " number of colors
        set t_Co=16
        " ANSI background
        set t_AB=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t%p1%{40}%+%e%p1%{92}%+%;%dm
        " ANSI foreground
        set t_AF=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t%p1%{30}%+%e%p1%{82}%+%;%dm
    elseif &term == 'term' || &term == 'rxvt' || &term == 'vt100' || &term == 'screen'
        " Less-Cool Terminals (no terminfo)
        set t_Co=16
        set t_AB=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{32}%+%d;1%;m
        set t_AF=^[[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{22}%+%d;1%;m
    else
        " Terminals that have trustworthy terminfo entries
        if &term == 'vt220'
            set t_Co=8
            " foreground
            set t_Sf=^[[3%dm
            " background
            set t_Sb=^[[4%dm
        elseif $TERM == 'xterm'
            set term=xterm-color
        endif
    endif
endif


" enable filetype detection
if version >= 600
    filetype plugin indent on
else
    filetype on
endif
" make sure we have colors first
if &t_Co > 2 || has("gui_running")
    syntax on
endif
```

Comment: Something changed:

`^[[96m//#include <unistd.h>

^[[94m#include ^[[95m"bouchonWifi.h"

^[[94m#include ^[[95m"string.h"`

The number aren't the same :/

Comment: :/ not sure what to say, you could try starting vim in vervose mode: vim -V9myVimLog

Comment: that will create myVimLog, you can copy the relevant output in your question

Comment: Why was this code snipped, dreaming of being an answer, marked as correct solution? The OP themselves posted a comment indicating that colors still don't work using this.